# .NET MAUI Picker binding with ViewModel file

Tags: .net, mvvm, maui, picker, maui-community-toolkit

I am developing an .net maui app and tried to add picker on one of app's pages. As is written in microsoft documentation ("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker"), I can create a list of Items directly in xaml file, but I need to declare this list in ViewModel class in order to make data binding.

Here is my code:
XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PlumbingCompany.Views.Page7_RepairReport_1_"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PlumbingCompany.Data"
             Title="7. Repair Report (1)">

          <StackLayout Margin="20,10,20,10">
                    <Label Text="Condition Found*" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
                    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding GetConditions}"> 
          </StackLayout>
```

XAML.cs

```
using PlumbingCompany.Data;

namespace PlumbingCompany.Views;

public partial class Page7_RepairReport_1_ : ContentPage
{
    public Page7_RepairReport_1_(Page7ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using PlumbingCompany.Models;
using PlumbingCompany.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace PlumbingCompany.Data
{
    public partial class Page7ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Page7ViewModel()
        {

        }

        public List<string> GetConditions()
        {
            return new List<string>
            {
               "Yes",
               "NA",
               "Dirty",
               "New"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't display any Item in picker's menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDj6q.png)

I  tried different ways to declare list through observable collection, array but it hasn't helped.

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `GetConditions` is a `method` not a `property`

Comment: Jason, thank you for youranswer. But can this property be of list or observablecollection type?

Comment: You can't bind to a method. If you look in Output pane, it should show a warning that `GetConditions` was not found. It needs to be a public property. `public List<string> GetConditions { get { return new List<string> { ... }; } }` or `public List<string> GetConditions  => new List<string> { ... };`

Comment: it can be any `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using  [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject) in your project, you need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker#set-the-itemssource-property) to an `IList` collection in your Page7ViewModel like below:

```
public partial class Page7ViewModel : ObservableObject 
{
        [ObservableProperty]
        public List<string> getConditions;

        public Page7ViewModel ()
        {
            GetConditions = new List<string>() {

                  "Yes",
                  "NA",
                  "Dirty",
                  "New"
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, this variant with usage of CommunityToolkit.Mvvm [ObservableProperty] works. Thank you very much! :)